# Django: at what point does SessionMiddleware check the database to see if a session is already in existence?

Tags: django, session, django-sessions

I'm trying to understand how session works in Django. Looking at the source code of `SessionMiddleware`:

```
class SessionMiddleware(object): 
    def process_request(self, request): 
        engine = import_module(settings.SESSION_ENGINE) 
        session_key = request.COOKIES.get(settings.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME, None) 
        request.session = engine.SessionStore(session_key)
```

If I understand it correctly, for every request 
`SessionMiddleware.process_request()` will get the `sessionid` from the 
cookie and then create a new `SessionStore` instance using that 
`sessionid`.

And when I looked at the source for `__init__()` of `SessionStore` and 
`SessionBase`:

```
  class SessionStore(SessionBase): 
      def __init__(self, session_key=None): 
          super(SessionStore, self).__init__(session_key) 

  class SessionBase(object): 
      def __init__(self, session_key=None): 
          self._session_key = session_key 
          self.accessed = False 
          self.modified = False
```

So basically `SessionStore` just creates a new instance without trying 
to look up in the database to see whether a session with the specified `sessionid` already exists 
or not. But shouldn't that be the whole point of session -- that for every 
request Django needs to look up in the session database to see if the 
session is already there? I'm guessing at some place this database lookup 
takes place but I can't find it.

Can you tell me where can i find it? Or did I misunderstand how 
session work in Django?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The third line of SessionMiddleware invokes a specific *session engine*, which dictates which SessionStore to use.

If you go down into contrib/sessions/backends/base.py, you'll see the following code:

```
class SessionBase(object):

    ...

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self._session[key]

    def _get_session(self, no_load=False):
        """
        Lazily loads session from storage (unless "no_load" is True, when only
        an empty dict is stored) and stores it in the current instance.
        """
        self.accessed = True
        try:
            return self._session_cache
        except AttributeError:
            if self._session_key is None or no_load:
                self._session_cache = {}
            else:
                self._session_cache = self.load()
        return self._session_cache

    _session = property(_get_session)
```

What this does is create a session *proxy* object, which the middleware has attached to the request.  It does not load the session object from the database until you say:

```
x = request.session['key']
```

At which point, the `__getitem__(self, key)` attempts to dereference `self._session`, which (being a property) in turn returns a cached copy of the session dictionary for this transaction, or if no cache is available, fetches it from the store using the `load()` method.  The `load()` method is implemented by specific child engines: database, file, cache, cache + db, etc.

`SessionStore` is a lightweight proxy for a full session; it only becomes a full session, hitting the database, when you need to read or write data to the session object associated with the key encoded in the session id cookie.